# Android Application crash due to the crash in any third party library project

Tags: android, crash, keyboard

In my android application i am using a third party library for keyboard. i have integrated it successfully and it works fine but i have one issue.

Sometimes this library project crash resulting crash in my application.

Is there any way if the crash happen in library project then my app not crash ?

Please help.

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.indexOf(int)' on a null object reference
04-15 12:56:42.856 4765-4765/com.mse.monumentalnetworks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:1941)
04-15 12:56:42.856 4765-4765/com.mse.monumentalnetworks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ContextImpl.getFileStreamPath(ContextImpl.java:549)
04-15 12:56:42.856 4765-4765/com.mse.monumentalnetworks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getFileStreamPath(ContextWrapper.java:193)
04-15 12:56:42.856 4765-4765/com.mse.monumentalnetworks E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.snaps.generic_emojikeyboard.AdapterEmoji.getView(AdapterEmoji.java:77)
04-15 12:56:42.856 4765-4765/com.mse.monumentalnetworks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
04-15 12:56:42.856 4765-4765/com.mse.monumentalnetworks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1440)
04-15 12:56:42.856 4765-4765/com.mse.monumentalnetworks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:366)
04-15 12:56:42.856 4765-4765/com.mse.monumentalnetworks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:307)
04-15 12:56:42.856 4765-4765/com.mse.monumentalnetworks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:442)
04-15 12:56:42.856 4765-4765/com.mse.monumentalnetworks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1283)
04-15 12:56:42.856 4765-4765/com.mse.monumentalnetworks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
```

Comment: Check if you are using the updated library in your gradle and show us the logcat output

Comment: its a library project for custom keyboard. how can i handle  in my application if any crash happen in that library project

Comment: I think a try/catch at this part in your app where the crashing method from the library is called should work....

Comment: Did you read my comment  ? I said to update all the library and show us the logcat output

Comment: yup i updated all of the library.

Comment: post your logcat  output?

Comment: updated..but it is the crash of library project. my question was that is there any way to handle it our side.

Comment: Well if you are saying that com.snaps.generic_emojikeyboard.AdapterEmoji.getView(AdapterEmoji.java:77) is from the library then use try/catch as @Opiatefuchs said or find another library to do the work for you

Comment: that´s what I mean. Look which call of a library method is  causing this error. And if you can´t avoid the crash, you can set try/catch on your method which calls the lib method. For example, you call methodA() from library which calls inside methodB() inside library. At this point, you have to try/catch it on your method which calls methodA()...